# CSS shows only at certain page widths

Tags: html, css

A weird event has occured that CSS only shows during mobile view, mobile browser parameters or when I just scale the website down.

this is the CSS related to the code

```
.right{
    background-color: green;
}
.languages hr{
    border-color:#68c3a3;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom:5px; margin-bottom:5px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="right">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    English
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">

    <ul>
      <li class="col-md-3" ><h4>Readng</h4> Good</li>
      <li class="col-md-3" ><h4> Speaking</h4> bad</li>
      <li class="col-md-3"  ><h4>Listening</h4> Terrible</li>
      <li class="col-md-3" ><h4>Understanding</h4> Mehh</li>
    </ul>
  </hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

the tag `.hr` doesn't show too if the page is at max width.

Comment: is your css inside a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)?

Comment: thought so too but no, I have no ``@media only`` line on my CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<hr>` not `</hr>` just change it and that will fix your problem!